# How to make a REST GET call to Twitter API?

Tags: json, rest, twitter

**beginner alert - first time using a REST API**

In my application, I am expecting to receive back a JSON object. My problem: what is the URL in the browser that I enter to receive a JSON object.

I tried the following URL:  "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%40twitterapi" (given at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search) but I get the following output:
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}

How I provide authentication data here?

I also tried to use the Console here: https://dev.twitter.com/console

I am able to get a successful reply (JSON data) when the "Request" is this. My question is - How do I make the "GET" request command into the format of "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/....."???

```
GET /1.1/search/tweets.json?q=drupal HTTP/1.1
X-HostCommonName:
api.twitter.com
Authorization:
OAuth oauth_consumer_key="DC0sePOBbQ8bYdC8r4Smg",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-    SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1385673977",oauth_nonce="1397646198",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_token="1681790569-ZTfDb37AggcbOk3wgtoJeUeLbGd3I2SYnul2XKI",oauth_signature="Pr82%2FkF3RzmUE%2BJqWGEgyEMsiQo%3D"
```

Host:
    api.twitter.com
    X-Target-URI:
    https://api.twitter.com
    Connection:
    Keep-Alive

I may have asked two questions above (based on 2 things I have tried), but my goal is one only - how to get a JSON data back from the twitter API?
(Also, please redirect me if this is not the right place for this question)

Answer (score 1):

To use Twitter API V1.1, you need to,

- Create an app first, in Twitter
- Get the Consumer key and Secret key
- Then use them in your app

Please visit the *Manage and create your applications* link under **REST API** [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use OAuth.

Ask a vague question, get a vague answer. If you want me to be more helpful, you'll have to specify a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not 100% sure about everything you are asking, I would suggest that you take a look at crafting your REST GET (and Posts) messages using a REST API Client such as Chrome's [Advanced REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US) or FireFox's [Rest Client](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/collections/tshivaram10/rest-client/) to work out the kinks.  These clients give you some basic fields to populate the data, allows you to test against a public REST API and you will able to see the URL that the client crafted.